# Has weirwood wood ever been used as material?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Weirwoods are sacred trees mostly found in the North, even if they were once spread throughout Westeros. I suppose that the old gods would be upset if they were cut down to be used as normal wood.
Has weirwood ever been used as material, either in the books or tv show?

Comment: I can't find anything on Google relating to "game of thrones" or "a song of ice and fire" and "barral wood" or "barral tree", so I'm not entirely sure what you're asking about. Do you mean weirwood? Is "barral wood" the term used in another language?

Comment: oh, yeah, barral is the french equivalent of weirwood

Comment: Well, when the Red Priestess came through, they were used as firewood at one point.

Comment: How much wood would a weirwood wear if a weirwood could wear wood? :P

Comment: @Bellatrix I just came here to leave that *exact* same comment! :-D

Comment: @Randal'Thor Great minds think alike! :D

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**TLDR:**
Yes, even if it's a rare and expensive material

**Long answer:**

Weirwood is said to be a very good quality wood, that doesn't even rot:

> It was a weirwood ancient and colossal, ten times the size of the one in the Stone Garden at Casterly Rock. This tree was bare and dead, though.
>   "The Brackens poisoned it," said his host. "For a thousand years it has not shown a leaf. In another thousand it will have turned to stone, the maesters say. Weirwoods never rot."
>
> <sub>A Dance with Dragons - Jaime I</sub>

There are several uses of the weirwood tree:

As material for weapons:

- Brynden Rivers' bow:

  Brynden Rivers, A.K.A. Bloodraven used a weirwood longbow, along with his private guards, The Raven's Teeth.

  > From Maidenpool had come Lord Mooton, from Raventree Lord Blackwood, from Duskendale Lord Darklyn. The royal demenses about King's Landing sent forth Hayfords, Rosbys, Stokeworths, Masseys, and the king's own sworn swords, led by three knights of the Kingsguard and stiffened by three hundred Raven's Teeth with tall white weirwood bows. Mad Danelle Lothston herself rode forth in strength from her haunted towers at Harrenhal, clad in black armor that fit her like an iron glove, her long red hair streaming. The light of the rising sun glittered off the points of five hundred lances and ten times as many spears. The night's grey banners were reborn in half a hundred gaudy colors. And above them all flew two regal dragons on night-black fields: the great three-headed beast of King Aerys I Targaryen, red as fire, and a white winged fury breathing scarlet flame. Not Maekar after all, Dunk knew, when he saw those banners. The banners of the Prince of Summerhall showed four three-headed dragons, two and two, the arms of the fourth-born son of the late King Daeron II Targaryen. A single white dragon announced the presence of the King's Hand, Lord Brynden Rivers.
  >   Bloodraven himself had come to Whitewalls.
  >
  > <sub>The Mystery Knight</sub>

  [image: Brynden Rivers]
- Bows of the Children of the Forest:

  > "They were a people dark and beautiful, small of stature, no taller than children even when grown to manhood. They lived in the depths of the wood, in caves and crannogs and secret tree towns. Slight as they were, the children were quick and graceful. Male and female hunted together, with weirwood bows and flying snares. Their gods were the gods of the forest, stream, and stone, the old gods whose names are secret. Their wise men were called greenseers, and carved strange faces in the weirwoods to keep watch on the woods. How long the children reigned here or where they came from, no man can know.
  >
  > <sub>A Game of Thrones - Bran VII</sub>
- Ygritte's bow:

  unlike in the TV-show, in the books, Ygritte have a bow made out of horn and weirwood

  > Ygritte trotted beside Jon as he slowed his garron to a walk. She claimed to be three years older than him, though she stood half a foot shorter; however old she might be, the girl was a tough little thing. Stonesnake had called her a "spearwife" when they'd captured her in the Skirling Pass. She wasn't wed and her weapon of choice was a short curved bow of horn and weirwood, but "spearwife" fit her all the same. She reminded him a little of his sister Arya, though Arya was younger and probably skinnier. It was hard to tell how plump or thin Ygritte might be, with all the furs and skins she wore.
  >
  > <sub>A Storm of Swords - Jon II</sub>
- Styr's spear:

  unlike in the TV-show, in the books, Styr have a spear made out of bronze and weirwood

  > It was then that he saw Styr. The Magnar was climbing up the barricade, over the gutted corn sacks and smashed barrels and the bodies of friends and foe alike. His bronze scale armor gleamed darkly in the firelight. Styr had taken off his helm to survey the scene of his triumph, and the bald earless whoreson was smiling. In his hand was a long weirwood spear with an ornate bronze head.
  >
  > <sub>A Storm of Swords - Jon VII</sub>

As material for buildings:

- The meeting table of the Kingsguard

  > The table itself was old weirwood, pale as bone, carved in the shape of a huge shield supported by three white stallions.
  >
  > <sub>A Storm of Swords, Jaime VIII</sub>

  [image: kingsguard]
- The throne of the Eyrie

  > The wretched boy had started it, looking down on him from a throne of carved weirwood beneath the moon-and-falcon banners of House Arryn. [...] Lady Lysa rose from her weirwood throne.
  >
  > <sub>A Game of Thrones - Tyrion V</sub>

  [image: eyrie throne]
- Moon Door of the Eyrie

  > Her small mouth twitched in a petulant smile. "If you are tried and found to be guilty of the crimes for which you stand accused, then by the king's own laws, you must pay with your life's blood. We keep no headsman in the Eyrie, my lord of Lannister. Open the Moon Door."
  >   The press of spectators parted. A narrow weirwood door stood between two slender marble pillars, a crescent moon carved in the white wood.
  >
  > <sub>A Game of Thrones - Tyrion V</sub>

  [image: moon door]
- Black gate of Nightfort

  > A turn or two later Sam stopped suddenly. He was a quarter of the way around the well from Bran and Hodor and six feet farther down, yet Bran could barely see him. He could see the door, though. The Black Gate, Sam had called it, but it wasn't black at all.
  >   It was white weirwood, and there was a face on it.
  >   A glow came from the wood, like milk and moonlight, so faint it scarcely seemed to touch anything beyond the door itself, not even Sam standing right before it. The face was old and pale, wrinkled and shrunken. It looks dead. Its mouth was closed, and its eyes; its cheeks were sunken, its brow withered, its chin sagging. If a man could live for a thousand years and never die but just grow older, his face might come to look like that.
  >
  > <sub>A Storm of Swords - Bran IV</sub>

  [image: black gate]
- The House of Black and White:
  One gate of the House of Black and White is made out of weirwood, the other beeing made out of ebony. the chairs are also made out of weirwood
  [image: house of black and white]

Answer (score 11):

## Yes

Dunk comes across a building where the rafters are made from weirwood trees.

> They seated the hedge knights well below the salt, closer to the doors than to the dais. Whitewalls was almost new as castles went, having been raised a mere forty years ago by the grandsire of its present lord. The smallfolk hereabouts called it the Milk house, for its walls and keeps and towers were made of finely dressed white stone, quarried in the Vale and brought over the mountains at great expense. Inside were floors and pillars of milky white marble veined with gold; **the rafters overhead were carved from the bone-pale trunks of weirwoods.** Dunk could not begin to imagine what all of that had cost.
>   <sub>The Mystery Knight</sub>

It is also mentioned that weirwood can be used as a material for bows.

> From Maidenpool had come Lord Mooton, from Raventree Lord Blackwood, from Duskendale Lord Darklyn. The royal demenses about King's Landing sent forth Hayfords, Rosbys, Stokeworths, Masseys, and the king's own sworn swords, led by three knights of the Kingsguard and **stiffened by three hundred Raven's Teeth with tall white weirwood bows.**
>   <sub>The Mystery Knight</sub>

We also see weirwood spears, Styr has one in an encounter with Jon.

> It was then that he saw Styr. The Magnar was climbing up the barricade, over the gutted corn sacks and smashed barrels and the bodies of friends and foe alike. His bronze scale armor gleamed darkly in the firelight. Styr had taken off his helm to survey the scene of his triumph, and the bald earless whoreson was smiling. **In his hand was a long weirwood spear with an ornate bronze head.**
>   <sub>A Storm of Swords, Jon VII</sub>

The meeting table of the Kingsguard is made from weirwood.

> **The table itself was old weirwood**, pale as bone, carved in the shape of a huge shield supported by three white stallions.
>   <sub>A Storm of Swords, Jaime VIII</sub>

The Moon Door and the throne in the Eyrie are made of weirwood.

> The press of spectators parted. **A narrow weirwood door** stood between two slender marble pillars, a crescent moon carved in the white wood.
>   <sub>A Game of Thrones, Tyrion V</sub>

> The wretched boy had started it, looking down on him from a **throne of carved weirwood** beneath the moon-and-falcon banners of House Arryn.
>   <sub>ibid</sub>

There are other examples too; see [the Wiki of Ice and Fire page](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Weirwood#Material) for a more complete breakdown though.

Answer (score 1):

Harrenhal.  In Clash of Kings, Catelyn's Uncle tells her that King Harren the Black wanted the highest Castle and spent 40 years building Harrenhal. Weirwoods were cut down for beams and rafters.

Comment: This is a good answer, as this detail was not mentioned in the existing ones, but consider [editing it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/204534/edit) to add the actual quote from the book to make it even better.